# Installer fails with "failed to register" error for certain DLLs

Tags: dll, build, com, vb6

I developped a vb6 program then I build an installation wizard with visual studio interdev.

I used "dependency walker" and "process explorer" to find out the missing DLLs  but there is always a problem with :

```
IESHIMS.DLL
WER.DLL
MPR.DLL
```

These dlls shown by dependency walker.

And when installing the program on another machine I have these error  messages :

```
uxtheme.dll failed to register
msdatsrc.tlb failed to register etc..
```

PS : no problem on a machine where visual studio is installed.

Any Idea to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: IESHIMS.DLL WER.DLL these dlls are not shown anymore in dependency walker after uninstalling ie8. But I have always the problem of missing dlls.

Answer (score 6):

Dependency Walker is not an appropriate tool to troubleshoot VB6 dependencies.  It works well enough for DLLs written in C or C++ that use implicit dependencies.  Although it hasn't kept up with the times and has trouble with DLLs that are stored in the Windows side-by-side cache or are delay loaded.  Delay loading is what generates the warnings on ieshims.dll et al.

VB6 uses COM, which loads DLLs dynamically with LoadLibrary().  You'll never see such a dependency back in Depends unless you use the Profile option.  Such DLLs are found back through the registry, the reason you needed to write an installer and tinker with regsvr32.exe.

You have to be pretty careful when writing installers like that, VB6 is *old* and can depend on operating system components that have been updated many times since 1998.  Like uxtheme.dll, an important operating system DLL that implements visual styles.  Having your installer overwrite the existing one on the user's machine is, well, disastrous.  Although it is probably protected by Windows through its File System Protection feature, something that got added as a counter-measure against broken installers.

Giving proper advice is here difficult beyond "do no harm".  A commercial installer like InstallShield or Wise (which I liked back then) is the best way to avoid shooting off the customer's leg.  Fairly sure they still support VB6 installs.  Microsoft makes a pre-cooked installer available for VB6 that installs all the core vb6 runtime components.  You can [download it here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24417).

Comment: This was answer #8888 for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You should ALWAYS double check and verify any dependancies that you think your application needs.
All the files you mentioned are system DLLs and MUST NOT be distributed.

For a VB6 application you need the basic runtimes, and any DLLs you explicitly reference/use if and only if you have permission from the authors of those DLLs and instructions on the correct procedure and location for installing them.

For the standard Microsoft provided OCX files, these normally just need to be copied to the system32 folder and registered.
See redist.txt in the root of your Visual Studio installation for more details.